# How to write physical units

Tags: support, mathjax

Units have to be written in an upright font. One normally does it this way:

`$1.2 \times 10^3\,\mathrm{\frac{J}{mol}}$`

> $1.2 \times 10^3\,\mathrm{\frac{J}{mol}}$

(see [Hidden points of editing you probably didn't know](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know/3045#3045))

Is there another way, with less typing?

Comment: Can we please not promote display-style fractions (`\frac{}{}`) for units? It is really bad style, not recommended by most scientific style guides…

Comment: @F'x The _display-style_ fractions “$\displaystyle C_{\mathrm m,p} = 33.58\ \mathrm{\frac{J}{K \cdot mol}}$” are actually in accordance with [the SI](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/) as well as ISO 80000. However, you are right that the relevant style guides stipulate that, where it is necessary to include fractions **in the body text**, they shall be reduced to a single level by using a solidus (/) or, where applicable, the negative index: “$C_{\mathrm m,p} = 33.58\ \mathrm{J/(K \cdot mol)}$” or “$C_{\mathrm m,p} = 33.58\ \mathrm{J\cdot K^{-1} \cdot mol^{-1}}$”.

Comment: Anyway, the small _inline style_ of MathJax “$C_{\mathrm m,p} = 33.58\ \mathrm{\frac{J}{K \cdot mol}}$” is only a makeshift solution and not proper typography.

Comment: Furthermore, there is no reference for the use of a small space `\,` for units in the SI guidelines, ISO and other standards, and IUPAC recommendations. They only stipulate the use of "a space".

Comment: Interesting point. For decades, quantity and and have been separated by `\,` in LaTeX, going back to Knuth and explained in countless books. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128053/73371 states that ISO and SI only talk about spaces in general, but not their width and only an unofficial translation of the SI standard lead to the indirect interpretation to have a normal space between quantity and unit. `siunitx`changed to a normal space in 2014.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of `\mathrm` many people misused `\ce`, because it was shorter to type. Seeing this, the author of `\ce` added a little goodie into the `mhchem` extension. You can type

`$\pu{1.2E3 J//mol}$`

> $\pu{1.2E3 J//mol}$

From the [documentation](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/#pu):

Multiplication

`\pu{123 J s}` $\pu{123 J s}$

`\pu{123 J*s}` $\pu{123 J*s}$

Division

`$\pu{123 kJ/mol}$` $\pu{123 kJ/mol}$

`$\pu{123 kJ//mol}$` $\pu{123 kJ//mol}$

`$\pu{123 kJ mol-1}$` $\pu{123 kJ mol-1}$
(`mol-1` = `mol^{-1}` = `mol^-1`)

`$\pu{123 kJ*mol-1}$` $\pu{123 kJ*mol-1}$

`$\pu{123 cm3}$` $\pu{123 m3}$
(`cm3` = `cm^{3}` = `cm^3`)

Scientific Notation

`$\pu{1.2e3 kJ}$` $\pu{1.2e3 kJ}$

`$\pu{1.2E3 kJ}$` $\pu{1.2E3 kJ}$

Comment: This is very convenient! However,  the current Stack Exchange Android App (Version 1.0.89) does not render `\pu`, but casts an error: *Undefined control sequence `\pu`*. Tested on a Fire 7 tablet with FireOS 5.3.2.o with added Google Play Store.

Comment: Could you add in the next version that `\circ` will be automatically raised, or some kind of shortcut for degree? That would be grand :D

Comment: @Martin-マーチン `$\pu{15 ^\circ C}$` and `$\pu{15 ^oC}$` work. Or do you mean geometrical degrees? They are not included yet (and strictly speaking, they are no physical unit).