# mhchem in Android app configured differently

Tags: bug, mathjax, android-app

Bugreport. Take a look at [How to write physical units](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-to-write-physical-units/3287#comment4729_3287) in the Android app (I did with version 1.0.89), you will see that `\pu` does not render on Android, while it does in the web version.

Comment: We should probably migrate this to [meta.se]. I couldn't find any evidence, that this has already been reported. I am not sure mhchem is only loaded on chemistry or also other sites, so we might not be the only ones affected. The set-up might also be different and there is a good chance that the MathJax versions are just at different development stages. Iirc `\dfrac{}{}` doesn't render either. (cc @orthocresol )

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where this should go. Issues with MathJax generally belong on meta.SE, but mhchem is only loaded on Chem.Se and Bio.SE (afaik) so it may be better to leave it here, especially since I recall reading that the devs drop by per-site metas to check for bugs as well. On the topic of dfrac, there's a number of MathJax commands that don't render on the mobile apps. I can only test with the iOS apps but I wouldn't be surprised to find that they don't work on Android either. I had plans to try to compile a list of such commands, but not right now.

Comment: This is most likely a configuration difference, not an issue with MathJax itself or the version used.  Both the mhchem extension and the AMSmath extension (that defined `\dfrac`) are optional components, and need to be loaded in the configuration.  If the Android app has a different configuration from the main site, that could account for the missing features.

Comment: Martin (Hensel), thanks for picking up my earlier comment on the problems with `\pu` in the Android app. As for the intended migration to Meta Stack Exchange, there's a again a good chance that the request will be closed as too specific. The same did happen on the earlier request to [enable mhchem on Chemistry.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130427/please-enable-mathjax-mhchem-extension-on-chemistry-se) in 2012.

Comment: It's sad that nearly half an year later this is still a problem :(