# Should fractional units be displayed as fractions or as negative exponents

Tags: discussion, formatting

The comments in [this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-to-write-physical-units) post discuss this issue, though without a clear conclusion unless I'm missing something.

For something as simple as grams per mole for example, there are actually several ways of displaying the units:

1) g/mol
2) $\mathrm{g/mol}$
3) $\mathrm{g~mol^{-1}}$
4) $\mathrm{g\dot\ mol^{-1}}$
5) $\mathrm{\frac{g}{mol}}$

And probably more.

I suspect that 3 is the best way in-line and either 3 or 5 when not in-line? I don't know, that's why I'm asking ;)

But to reiterate my main question: should fractional units be displayed as fractions or as negative exponents. And if the answer is "depends", then on what?

Comment: You should really stop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) sometime, airhuff. Things like this get batted around a lot. (A lot of the time nothing ever really *happens* about them, but we talk about them... ;-)

Comment: @hBy2Py Try typing `[chat]` in a comment ;) Also, you either lost your mouth, or you forgot to close your parentheses. Tut-tut.

Comment: @orthocresol `[chat]` doesn't go straight to Periodic Table, though.  I used to double the parenthesis in this kind of situation, but I ended up deciding that I preferred the syntactic irregularity to the visual unpleasantness of the double-paren. (I'm one of those types that will use square brackets, curly braces, etc. in regular text.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since we're not a professional publishing house, and since there's no ultimate editorial authority enforcing conformity to style, I suspect the ultimate answers to your questions are indeed:

1. Depends.
2. On however any given author feels like formatting them.

Thus, if a post has units formatted in a way that is unambiguous and sufficiently easy to read, those units expressions should just be **left alone**.

In situations where the units are poorly formatted by whatever measure, though—misspelled, wrong punctuation, ambiguous, etc.—I'd be mildly in favor of establishing a semi-formal site-wide recommendation for how they be formatted. I tend to prefer $\#3$, myself, as it is cleaner than $\#4$ (despite [Loong's comment](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-to-write-physical-units#comment4265_3286) using $\#4$ at the linked post) and usually makes it less ambiguous as to which quantities are in the numerator/denominator. That said, $\#2$ involves a lot less typing, which is worth something. I do think any recommendation should include the use of MathJax since exponents will often be required, which leaves out $\#1$.  Per [Loong's other comment](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-to-write-physical-units#comment4266_3286) $\#5$ should apparently be shunned (**SHUNNED**) in polite technical discourse. (Full disclosure: I've formatted inline units that way more than once. **{{{SHAME}}}**)

Despite all that: as long as an edit re-formats unit expressions in a way that is unambiguous and sufficiently easy to read, they should just be **left alone**. We should strongly discourage Unit Expression Purity Edit Rampages™ (UEPERs™, pronounced "weepers") as it's just simply not worth people's time and they'd result in a lot of flooding of the front page.