# Adding tex symbols to post

Tags: discussion, mathjax

This is a two part question:

1. The extent to which tex can be incorporated into a post appears to be outlined [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ) (some links from that question need refreshing btw). Is this the main source of information on tex incorporation/rendering in general or should I consult another post?
2. [This question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/127632/regarding-the-infinitesimal-form-of-the-first-law-of-thermodynamics) would have gained from inclusion of the "d-slashed" symbol. I found tex representations of this symbol in package tipa (as \textcrd). Any other way this symbol could be included?

I realize this is probably a dupe of sorts. Links to "authoritative" posts are very welcome since I was unable to find an answer.

I have also also looked through the sandboxes, so far no luck, despite the impressive array of nifty symbols on display. Ironically orthocresol apologizes there about not using proper notation for the inexact differential :-).

Note that the d-slash symbol is the last in the list in Martin's answer. I understand that tex and mathjax are not the same thing, but having seen various tex items implemented I thought this was one way to go. I have also seen [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/how-to-render-angstrom-and-parts-per-notations-in-mathjax) implementation of the Angstrom symbol using \AA via \require.

Comment: Your page is about some special cases. The main starting point should probably be [this one](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/7951) followed by [this guide](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/444/7951).

Comment: You can find many other bits and pieces on meta, e.g. [signs](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2896/7951), [operators](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2897/7951), [functions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2898/7951), [more functions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2899/7951), [quantities and units](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2900/7951), [horizontal space](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2947/7951), and [vertical space](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2941/7951).

Comment: @Loong Ok, thank you! I thought of mentioning the sandbox but then thought twice since I found it somewhat chaotic rummaging and didn't find the symbol there.

Answer (score 2):

## MathJax is not (La)TeX

In essence, MathJax is an implementation of mathematical rendering, which is able to interpret a subset of commands in (La)TeX syntax. Don't expect too much of it, it is very limited, and do not confuse it with LaTeX. (Questions about MathJax are off-topic for [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).)

For any beginner, the most basic tutorial is [how can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) More about editing in general can be found in [hidden points of editing you probably didn't know](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3044/4945). There is much more on MathJax usage available here on meta. The one you have linked to, [What additional formatting features are available to MathJax (possibly via \require{})?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3540/4945), is very advanced, and I am personally not a big fan of most of it.

If you have ***a lot*** of time, you can visit the [first sandbox](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/111/4945), I believe Loong has tested everything (and more) possible with MathJax. Just keep in mind that this applies to MathJax only. Obviously, you can play around in the newer sandbox, too, if you are looking for something specific.

Adding symbols to MathJax is often requested. Especially on our platform, `upgreek` is very much demanded. However, this is something for the development team there, please refer to the [official MathJax Documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html). You may report issues and feature requests via GitHub, just as [this one for said upgreek](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/382).

---

For specific symbols, if they exist in unicode, they can possibly be interpreted by MathJax, so just try to include them as such.

I am not sure about the d-slash symbol you are describing, but following things I could imagine:

- $\not d$ `$\not d$`
- $\rlap{d}/$ `$\rlap{d}/$`
- $\rlap{d}-$ `$\rlap{d}-$`
- $\rule[0.5ex]{1.5ex}{0.1ex}\llap{d}$ `$\rule[0.5ex]{1.5ex}{0.1ex}\llap{d}$`
- $\require{cancel}$$\cancel{d}$ `$\cancel{d}$` (with `\require{cancel}`)
- $đ$ `$đ$`

Comment: Thanks, the d-slash symbol is the last in your list. Looks like you copied the symbol, I'm guessing its unicode? I understand btw that tex and mathjax are not the same thing, but having seen various tex items implemented I thought this was one way to go. I have also seen [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/how-to-render-angstrom-and-parts-per-notations-in-mathjax) implementation of the Angstrom symbol using \AA via \require.

Comment: Looks then like the way to proceed is to request a new mathjax feature or copy-paste unicode, which as in the Angstrom symbol might be simpler.

Comment: @Buck It'll take much time before a feature makes it into MathJax, and then it might not be available for us right away as I am not entirely sure which version SE is linking to. The last one is simply unicode copied, it is easiest, but that also depends like most of MathJax on the fonts your browser is using. So it might look very odd on other devices. Btw, the correct way two write one angstrom is $\pu{100 pm}$.

Comment: Hmm, the recommended or standard way, not the correct way, I would say :-) Thanks for your help.